# Calibrating xsens IMU

Tags: ros, xsens

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi every one,
I have a Xsens MTi IMU,
When I get data from it using xsens_driver in ros, I found some numbers that are not the real numbers.
when IMU is stable I see numbers and not changing, these numbers like accelartion should be zero but they aren't.

I think my sensor need a calibration. but I can not do it.
any one can help how to calibrate this sensor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84891/calibrating-xsens-imu/) by [narenji](https://answers.ros.org/users/6112/narenji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-09-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try to subscribe imu topic with rostopic echo :

```
---
header:
seq: 288
stamp:
secs: 1330631562
nsecs: 789304161
frame_id: xsens_mti_imu
orientation:
x: 0.00401890464127
y: -0.00402884092182
z: 0.679586052895
w: 0.73357373476
...
---
```

If you observe the orientation field, you will see four variables instead of three,
as you would probably expect. This is because in ROS, the spatial orientation is
represented using quaternions.

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The numbers shouldn't be zero. As it's real sensor data expect some noise on that, so x,y accel should be about zero. z acceleration usually has a magnitude around 9.81.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1